# openapi-core library, validate_response method does not validare response properties

Tags: python, openapi

I got the following open api 3.0 schema

main.yaml:

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: blabla
  description: description

  termsOfService: 'TBD'
  contact:
    email: asd@email
  version: 1.1.9999
externalDocs:
  description: Find out more about Swagger
  url: 'http://swagger.io'
servers:
  - url: https://dummy_server.com/

tags:
  - name: login
    description: login


components:
  securitySchemes:
    bearerAuth:
      type: http
      scheme: bearer

paths:
  /local/sub/{user}/duration:
    $ref: './methods/local/sub-user-duration.yaml'
```

Content of './methods/local/sub-user-duration.yaml':

```
get:


security:
    - bearerAuth: []
  tags:
    - duration
  summary: summ
  description: desc
  operationId: getDurationLimit
  parameters:
    - name: user
      in: path
      description: user
      required: true
      schema:
        type: integer
        format: int64
  responses:
    '400':
      description: Bad Request
      content:
        'application/json':
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              timestamp:
                type: string
              status:
                type: integer
              error:
                type: string
              path:
                type: string
```

I m using openapi-core lib with python as such:

Calling the api:

```
import requests

response = requests.post(url=url, params=query_params, headers=headers)

self.validate_request_swagger(response.request)
self.validate_response_swagger(response)
```

Openapi-core request & response validations:

```
from openapi_core import Spec

from openapi_core import validate_request
from openapi_core import validate_response
from openapi_core.contrib.requests import RequestsOpenAPIRequest
from openapi_core.contrib


def get_partner_spec(self):
    spec_ = Spec.from_file_path(str(self.get_project_root()) + "/docs/main.yaml")
    return spec_

def validate_request_swagger(self, request):
    request = RequestsOpenAPIRequest(request)
    validate_request(request=request, spec=self.get_partner_spec())

def validate_response_swagger(self, response):
    request = RequestsOpenAPIRequest(response.request)
    response = RequestsOpenAPIResponse(response)
    validate_response(response=response, spec=self.get_partner_spec(), request=request)
```

APi response:

```
{
   "timestamp":"2023-03-03T11:26:26.293+00:00",
   "status":400,
   "error":"Bad Request",
   "path":"/local/sub/1647222638/duration"
}
```

The problem is it only validates the status code, but not the properties, i can define path as integer in yaml, it still passes, i can even remove all the properties still passes..

For request properties it works e'ko

Answer (score 0):

I checked your example and (after fixing the example code) it works fine.

I noticed you have `get` method in your spec but send `post` in "calling api". Maybe that's why you don't get any validation errors because you change wrong schema?

Check the example here https://replit.com/@p1c2u/StackOverflow75626639#main.py